# In PHP, how do I use the GD library created image directly on my website

Tags: php, html, gd, captcha

I'm not sure I understand quite how this works.  For a website form I'd like to generate a random captcha image and display it along with the form.  So ideally I would like something along those lines:

```
<form action="post.php" method="post">
  ...
  <?php create_captcha(); ?>
</form>
```

While I do have a function which creates an image resource in PHP ([link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php))

```
function create_captcha() {
  $w = 60; $h = 30;
  $img = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
  ...
  //header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
  imagejpeg($img);
}
```

I can't quite figure out how to output that image directly onto the website as part of the HTML form.  My suspicion is that I'll have to save it into a temporary file `captcha.jpg` and then generate a `<img src="captcha.jpg" />` into the website.

Is there a more elegant way without using a temporary image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use your captcha generation file path as source of IMG tag

```
<img src="http://domain.com/your-captcha_generating-file-path" />
```

Comment: Wait.. that simple?  I stuffed the body of the `create_captcha()` function into its own captcha.php file, and simply call it from the form with a `<img src="php/captcha.php" alt="" />`.  Works like a charm :)

Comment: How can I add `header()` to this? I would like to set `header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");` to ensure that the capture image isn't cached.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
function getCaptcha() {

    // Begin output buffering
    ob_start();

    // generate the captcha image in some magic way
    $w = 60; $h = 30;
    $img = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
    imagejpeg($img);

    // and finally retrieve the byte stream
    $rawImageBytes = ob_get_clean();

    return "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode( $rawImageBytes ) . "' />";
}
```

By using a Base64 encoded data source in your img tag, you won't have to store any temporary files at all.

Comment: Thanks!  I do remember embedding image data into the website (way back when) but I couldn't figure out how to do this in PHP.  Thanks for the code above though, it would be a good solution if the @San's wouldn't be cleaner.

Comment: You're welcome. As a matter of fact, I've upvoted @San's answer as well cause it's simpler. :D

Comment: Thanks bro. It saves my lot of time.